# Error con tabs en Móviles con JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, programación-móvil

Hola tengo un problema al cargar mi código en sitio web funciona correctamente en pc pero en tablets y teléfonos por alguna razón deja de funcionar,

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$( document ).ready(function() {
 console.log( "ready!" );
 $('ul.tabs-form > li a:first').addClass('active');
 $('.secciones > article').hide();
 $('.secciones > article#tab1').show();

 $('ul.tabs-form > li > a').click(function(){
    $('ul.tabs-form > li > a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.secciones > article.contenido').hide();

    var activeTab = $(this).attr('href');
    $(activeTab).show();
    return false;
 });
});
</script>
```

Y este es el html

```
<div class="wrap">
 <ul class="tabs-form">
  <li><a href="#tab1"><span class="fa fa-home"></span><span class="tab-text">Inicio</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab2"><span class="fa fa-group"></span><span class="tab-text">Nosotros</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab3"><span class="fa fa-briefcase"></span><span class="tab-text">Servicios</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab4"><span class="fa fa-bookmark"></span><span class="tab-text">Blog</span></a></li>
 </ul>

<div class="secciones">
  <article class="contenido" id="tab1">
    <h1>Inicio</h1>
    <p>Lorem1</p>
  </article>
  <article class="contenido" id="tab2">
    <h1>Nosotros</h1>
    <p>Lorem2</p>
  </article>
  <article class="contenido" id="tab3">
    <h1>Servicios</h1>
    <p>Lorem3</p>
  </article>
  <article class="contenido" id="tab4">
    <h1>Blog</h1>
    <p>Lorem4</p>
  </article>
</div>
```

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: ¿Puedes brindar más información? ¿Qué hace en móvil? ¿Cómo es su comportamiento?

Comment: @Hoose Ahora el comportamiento en móvil es que al cargar el sitio aparece el contenido del primer tab pero al presionar otros el contenido ya no aparece, esto solo ocurre en móviles ya que en computadora el comportamiento es normal,

https://www.evernote.com/l/AZLnZOSjLyVMbLSh-o5ck6HuNOOFWzsbtKs
https://tag.com.gt/
Te dejo mi sitio por si quieres revisar el comportamiento más detallado, ¿Crees que sea por compatibilidad de archivos?
Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: No veo algún error como para que no te funcione en dispositivos, comienzo a pensar en que podría deberse a que tienes algún elemento por arriba de las tabs y por eso no puedes darle click, comprueba que no sea algo de eso. De no serlo, tienes como mostrarnos lo que no te funciona en alguna página?
gracias